# How to save Set of objects with SQL script?

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc, pojo

I have to create for test reason tables in SQL format.
They should be loaded for the test set up.
And after it, Service and DAO layer should be tested.

I have stuck at creating middle for Entities.

Here is `User` class:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Calendar birthday;
    private String email;
    private String role;
    private Set<Ticket> bookedTickets = new HashSet<>();
```

It contains a Set of Tickets.

Here is `Ticket` POJO:

```
public class Ticket {
    private Integer id;
    private Event event;
    private Double price;
    private User user;
```

It has ***User*** and ***Event*** instances.
If Ticket isn't assigned to any User (user == null) => it is free. If is => it is purchased.

`Event` and `Auditorium` POJO:

```
public class Event {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private EventRating eventRating;
    private Set<Calendar> eventDateTime;

public class Auditorium {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer numberOfSeats;
    private Set<Integer> vipSeats;
```

Event has Set of available dates, coz some event can be repeated during one day few times.

Getters and setters were omitted at code snippets.

Here is my `create-db.sql` script:

```
----------------------
-- Create Users table
----------------------
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_name      VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  user_birthday  DATETIME NULL,
  user_email     VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  user_role      VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  user_tickets   VARCHAR(100) NULL,  -- Here should be collection of objects
);

----------------------
-- Create Events table
----------------------
CREATE TABLE Events (
  event_id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  event_name     VARCHAR(30),
  event_price    DECIMAL(8,2),
  event_rating   VARCHAR(30),
  event_date     DATETIME,
);

---------------------------
-- Create Auditoriums table
---------------------------
CREATE TABLE Auditoriums (
  aud_id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  aud_name       VARCHAR(30),
  aud_seats      INTEGER,
  aud_vip        INTEGER,
);

-----------------------
-- Create Tickets table
-----------------------
CREATE TABLE Tickets (
  tick_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  event_id       VARCHAR(30),
  tick_price     DECIMAL(8,2),
  user_id        INTEGER,
);
```

here is `insert-data.sql`:

```
------------------------
-- Populate Users table
------------------------
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1, 'Garry Potter', '2001-05-01', 'potter@gmail.com', 'admin', NULL);
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (2, 'Ron Weasley',  '2000-05-01', 'ron@gmail.com', 'user', NULL);
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (3, 'Germiona Grendjer', '2000-05-01', 'germiona@gmail.com', 'user', NULL);

------------------------
-- Populate Events table
------------------------
INSERT INTO Events (event_id, event_name, event_price, event_rating, event_date)
VALUES (1, 'Green Mile', 60.0, 'high', '2016-02-28');
INSERT INTO Events (event_id, event_name, event_price, event_rating, event_date)
VALUES (2, 'Gone by the wind', 50.0, 'middle', '2016-02-28');
```

I am using `Spring JDBC` for working with DB.

***How to manage saving `Set<Ticket>` and `Set<Calendar>` with SQL script and support their unique as well?***

Comment: Are you talking about M-N relationship table?

Comment: @stjepano I suppose it should be `Many-to-one`

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want but `Many-to-one` are usually implemented with foreign key on `Many` side, in your `Tickets` table you already have `user_id` column, you need to make it a foreign key. Do you also want to enforce Set constraint (uniqueness of tickets in User)?

Comment: @stjepano I have updated question.